# First order differential equation: how do I prove that $u$ satisfies the differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

So I'm given this differential equation, that Bernoulli equation:
$$\frac{dy}{dx} + p(x)y = q(x)y^{n} $$

now it says:

> Show that if $y$ is the solution of the above Bernoulli differential
>   equation and $u = y^{1−n}$, then $u$ satisfies the linear differential
>   equation:
>
> $$\frac{du}{dx} + (n-1)p(x)y = (1-n)q(x)$$

I'm not sure how to prove this exactly

My plan is to substitute $u$ in there and show $rhs = y^3 *q(x)$ or something

first idea is to find $du/dx$
So $u=y^{1-n}$

So I know that by chain rule
 $$\frac{du}{dx} = \frac{du}{dy} \times \frac{dy}{dx} $$

I know that $\frac{du}{dy} = (1-n)y^{-n}$

now for $dy/dx$ i re-arrange $u=y^{1-n}$ to $u=\frac{y}{n}$,  $un=y$

Hence holding $u$ and $n$ constant
$$\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{d}{dx}(un) = 0 $$

$$ \frac{du}{dx} = (1-n)y^{-n}\times 0 = 0  $$

So subbing in $du/dx$ and this i get...

$$(1-n)p(x) = (1-n)q(x) $$

Comment: BTW this question is designed to solve $x^2y' +2xy = y^3$ to which my plan is to first divide both sides by $x^2$ then somehow use the knowledge from the above to explain it. (really more interested with the original question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Applying the chain rule to $u(x) = [y(x)]^{1-n}$ we obtain that 
\begin{align}
\frac{d u}{dx}(x)&= \frac{du}{dy}(y(x))\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}(x)\\
&= (1-n)[y(x)]^{-n}\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}(x)
\end{align}
Futhermore using the Bernoulli equation we have 
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=q(x)y^n-p(x)y
$$
and 
\begin{align}
\frac{d u}{dx}&= (1-n)y^{-n}\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}\\
&=(1-n)y^{-n}\cdot q(x)y^n - (1-n)y^{-n}\cdot p(x) y\\
&=(1-n)q(x) -(1-n)p(x)y^{1-n}\\
&=(1-n)q(x) -(1-n)p(x)u
\end{align}
indeed you prove that $u$ solves the equation 
$$
\frac{du}{dx}+(1-n)p(x)u = (1-n)q(x)
$$

Comment: Wow thank you so much! Thank you thank you thank you. I must've sat on this one for almost 2 hours.